# Angular-cli monorepo how to setup @src path alias

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, monorepo

I'm trying to port a project from a lerna bootstrap and bespoke webpack setup to a "plain" angular-cli setup.

I've followed along with this tutorial on setting up angular-cli with npm workspaces and lerna.
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-monorepo-lerna/

However, nowhere is mentioned how to setup typical @src path aliases to avoid fragile relative paths. The original project uses these heavily and it will be quite annoying to have to re-relativize everything.

I've google so many similar tsconfig path articles and posts, but they are all very confusing and nothing seems to work.

I'm a bit baffled why this wouldn't be something you always do.

I see that there are paths setup for the already transpiled js in the dist folder, but not for within the sub-project itself

Since I'm starting from scratch, I don't want to share what I already have. I want to know how you would do it with a simple angular-cli `ng new --no-create-application` `ng generate library foo` `ng generate application bar`

Comment: I do not want to be swimming upstream, if @src is some kind of anti-pattern, then what is the recommended method for avoiding relative paths within a project (in a monorepo)